# "sed" Insert Backslash to File

Tags: windows, bash, sed

**Tool**: Git Bash for Windows

**Problem**: Trying to insert the text "\connect central" at the top of each file in a directory.

**Code**:

```
for f in $DIR/*.sql; do
  sed -i "1i \\\connect central" $f
done
```

This does try to edit inline and insert my text, but three backslashes (like I've read everywhere) doesn't create the single backslash like I'm expected. Instead I get:

[image]

I've also tried some variants along the lines of:

```
for f in $DIR/*.sql; do
  sed -i -e "1i `\\\connect central`" $f
done
```

but that throws an error of `sed: -e expression #1, char 3: expected \ after`a', `c',`i'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use single quotes instead of double quotes. Backslash is an escape character inside double quotes, so you need to double it to pass it through to the `sed` command literally. It has no special meaning inside single quotes.

```
sed -i '1i \\\connect central' "$f"
```

To do it with double quotes (which you might need if there's variable content in the string you're inserting), you have to double all the backslashes:

```
sed -i "1i \\\\\\connect central" "$f"
```

For more information, see [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

Comment: And to explain further, the first backslash is required by the sed `i` command.  The backslash which follows must be escaped, as backslash-backslash, so that sed does not treat it specially.  Thus, three backslashes are needed by sed.

Comment: @John1024 That's already inherent in the command in the question. He knows what the correct `sed` command is, he's just having trouble passing it through from the shell.

Comment: Yeah, just couldn't get the right syntax and obviously, the quotes threw me for a loop. Thanks.

Comment: @Barmar I wasn't disagreeing.  I was just adding.  Your answer already has my +1.

Comment: @John1024 I understand that, I was just explaining why I didn't think that exposition was necessary for the answer.