# Mac OS Bash Sed yaml file with php file as string, backslash \n result only in n

Tags: bash, sed, yaml

I am modifying a yaml file which contains this:

```
name: config.php
data:
  config.php: <CONFIG_PHP_SECTION>
folder: test
```

Now, the config.php is something like this:

```
<?php
  /* This is a config
   */
  $app['env'] = 'sandbox';
  $app['db'] = [
    'host'=>'localhost'
  ]
```

Is there a way that I can either use awk or sed or perl to get to this:

```
name: config.php
data:
  config.php: "<?php\n  /* This is a config\n  */\n $app['env'] = 'sandbox';\n  $app['db'] = [\n    'host'=>'localhost'\n  ]"
folder: test
```

I've tried using `CONFIG=$(awk '{printf "%s\\n", $0}' config | tr '"' "\'")` to change newline to \n, and then `sed -i "" "s&<CONFIG_PHP_SECTION>&\"$CONFIG\"&" config.yaml`... However, all I got is a weird `<?phpn  /* This is a confign  */n $app['env'] = 'sandbox';n  $app['db'] = [n    'host'=>'localhost'n  ]`, a string without backward slash in front of the n.

I've also tried using `tr '\n' "\\n"` but all I get is an actual newline (which breaks the yaml file)

Is there anyway I can actually get \n displayed and save to the config.yaml in bash?

Thanks

p.s. The suggested duplication "["sed" Insert Backslash to File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47915522/sed-insert-backslash-to-file)" doesn't work for me... Could you elaborate more, @RobinGreen? Thanks!

When I did `sed -i "" 's&<CONFIG_PHP_SECTION>&"$CONFIG"&' config.yaml`, the output is

```
name: config.php
data:
  config.php: "$CONFIG"
folder: test
```

When I did `sed -i "" 's&<CONFIG_PHP_SECTION>&"'"$CONFIG"'"&' config.yaml`, then the output is the same as the one missing `\`.

Also... CONFIG is already `\\n`, it's just the last sed command that both `\` got deleted leaving `n` behind.

Comment: @RobinGreen Your suggestion doesn't work for me, could you elaborate more? Thanks (explained in the original post)

Comment: @Cyrus I would vote up/down or accept it when someone has post an answer. However, no one has answered anything when you post this... Is this like a reminder?

Comment: @snowmen10: yes, it's a reminder. You asked four questions and accepted no answer.